# Pygame update bug

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating my game on python with pygame but I have got a bug while updating screen :
[my older character position are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWWlV.png)

I am using a pattern to fill my screen and I refresh it each time and this before my character so it shouldn't be laggy, this is my code :

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Open Pygame window
taille_fenetre = [960, 640]
fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode(taille_fenetre)
pygame.key.set_repeat(400, 30)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Chargement et collage du fond
fond = pygame.image.load("brock.png").convert()
for a in range(taille_fenetre[0] // fond.get_width() + 1):
    for i in range(taille_fenetre[1] // fond.get_height() + 1):
        fenetre.blit(fond, (a*fond.get_width(),i*fond.get_height()))

room_size = (taille_fenetre[0]-64*2,taille_fenetre[1]-64*2)
room = pygame.Surface(room_size)
room.fill((255,0,0))
terre = pygame.image.load("terre.png").convert()
for a in range(room.get_width() // terre.get_width() + 1):
    for i in range(room.get_height() // terre.get_height() + 1):
        room.blit(terre, (a*terre.get_width(),i*terre.get_height()))

shadow_room = pygame.image.load('shadow_room.png')

def blit_alpha(target, source, location, opacity):
    x = location[0]
    y = location[1]
    temp = pygame.Surface((source.get_width(), source.get_height())).convert()
    temp.blit(target, (-x, -y))
    temp.blit(source, (0, 0))
    temp.set_alpha(opacity)        
    target.blit(temp, location)

class Personnage:
def __init__(self):
    self.imagesrc = "perso.png"
    self.image = pygame.image.load(self.imagesrc).convert_alpha()
    self.size = self.image.get_size()
    self.position = [0,0]
    self.vitesse = 5
    self.sante = 5
def bouger(self,facteur):
    self.position = [self.position[0] - self.vitesse * facteur[0],self.position[1] - self.vitesse * facteur[1]]
def afficher(self,fenetre):
    print(self.position)
    fenetre.blit(self.image,self.position)
#INFINITE LOOP
continuer = 1

perso = Personnage()
while continuer:
    relachex = True
    relachey = True

    #Re-collage
    fenetre.blit(fond, (0,0))
    fenetre.blit(room,(64,64))
    blit_alpha(room,shadow_room,(0,0),128)

    for event in pygame.event.get():        #Attente des événements
            if event.type == QUIT:
                    continuer = 0
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        perso.bouger([1,0])
    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        perso.bouger([-1,0])
    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        perso.bouger([0,-1])
    if keys[K_UP]:
        perso.bouger([0,1])
    #REFRESH
    perso.afficher(fenetre)
    pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Could you just check that your code indentation has made it to the forum correctly? I'm looking at the `Personnage` class specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are drawing over the previous images again and again without clearing out the old stuff. You can't tell with the other images because they are static, but it shows with the character. Add:

```
fenetre.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

to the top of your game loop to refresh the screen to draw the new locations.